# Giving control to app started from bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that tests for the existence of a running program (JoyToKey.exe), if it's not running, start it, if it is running, move on.

Once the app is running, I then launch another app (mgalaxy.exe) but although it is maximized and I can see it, it does not have control.  That is I need to do an  to get control of the running mgalaxy.exe.

How can I do this so that I don't need to do the .  It used to work perfectly on Windows 7, but under Windows 8.0 I have this problem.  Code in batch file is:

```
@echo off 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq JoyToKey.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "JoyToKey.exe">NUL
if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
  echo Launching JoyToKey
  cd C:\Mame\jtk374en
  START /MIN JoyToKey.exe
)
echo Launching mGalaxy
cd c:\Mame
start mgalaxy.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding timeout.  I'd be interested to hear how it goes, as I also found focus issues when launching programs from a batch file.  This worked for me when starting a text editor.

```
start mgalaxy.exe
timeout 3 /nobreak
exit
```

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately did not resolve my problem.  I still had to do a <alt><tab> to get mgalaxy active.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try increasing the 3 to 6 if your computer isn't a speed demon.  Also, put the three commands in a test batch file and launch that, to see if it works.  If you have other things in your batch file then they may interfere, so testing it this way is a good option to check the technique.